# Reset position on drag and drop script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make drag and drop script to move things in game but the thing this is for mobile devise.

I want to player not be able to drop item in place that should not be placed so I want to reset it position to startPostion.

The problem is in `OnMouseUp()` but I will send all of script. Here is the code that I wrote, and I have problem with it:

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Collider2D))]
public class DragAndDrop : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool isDragging;
    private Plane dragPlane;
    private Vector3 offset;
    private Camera myMainCamera;
    private Collider2D myCollider;
    private Vector3 startPosition;

    void Start() 
    {
        myMainCamera = Camera.main;
        myCollider = GetComponent<Collider2D>();
        startPosition = transform.position;
    }

    void OnMouseDown()   
    {
        startPosition = transform.position;
        isDragging = true;
        myCollider.isTrigger = true;

        dragPlane = new Plane(myMainCamera.transform.forward, transform.position);
        Ray camRay = myMainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        float planeDist;

        if (dragPlane.Raycast(camRay, out planeDist)) 
        {
            offset = transform.position - camRay.GetPoint(planeDist);
        }
    }

    void OnMouseDrag() 
    {
        Ray camRay = myMainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        float planeDist;

        if (dragPlane.Raycast(camRay, out planeDist)) 
        {
            Vector3 newPosition = camRay.GetPoint(planeDist) + offset;

            // Check if the new position is within the bounds of the object,
            // with some extra padding added to the edges
            Vector3 screenPoint = myMainCamera.WorldToScreenPoint(newPosition);
            Vector3 objectBounds = GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.extents;
            float paddingX = objectBounds.x * 0.5f; // Add 25% extra padding on each side
            float paddingY = objectBounds.y * 0.5f; // Add 25% extra padding on each side
            if (screenPoint.x > objectBounds.x - paddingX && screenPoint.x < Screen.width - objectBounds.x + paddingX
                                                          && screenPoint.y > objectBounds.y - paddingY && screenPoint.y < Screen.height - objectBounds.y + paddingY) 
            {
                transform.position = newPosition;
            }
        }
    }

    // void OnMouseUp() 
    // {
    //     isDragging = false;
    //     myCollider.isTrigger = false;
    // }

    void OnMouseUp() 
    {
        isDragging = false;
        myCollider.isTrigger = false;
    
        // Check if there is any collider under the item's position
        Collider2D hitCollider = Physics2D.OverlapBox(transform.position, myCollider.bounds.size, 0);

        if (hitCollider != null ) 
        {
            // There is a collider, so check if it is the same as the item's collider
            if (hitCollider != myCollider || hitCollider.CompareTag("Ground")) 
            {
                // The item was dropped on a different collider, so reset its position
                transform.position = startPosition;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I find overlapBox in unity document but it just not work properly.
I also forgot to mention its 2d Game and this script attached to 2d sprite in game.

I tried OverlapCircleAll method  but that not working optimal as well